# Getting the "size" of a view in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, sql-view

Essentially, I'm trying to figure out the size table `foo` will be after executing:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo AS (
    SELECT * FROM my_view
);
```

My gut tells me that the easiest approach would be to `SELECT count(1) FROM my_view` and multiply by the column widths, but that won't help me with VARCHARs.

Is there a "right" way to do this?

Comment: You could use `explain (analyze, verbose)` to get the execution plan. It reports the average size of each row and the total number of rows.

Comment: Why not just run it and see whether you are right?

Answer (score 0):

I also think that size might be based on the type of view.
A normal view should not have size on disk since it's merely pulls the results from an underlying table.
But if its a materialized view, then it would have size on disk

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31645336)